# S3 Batch operation error SrcGetObjectNotPermitted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have setup s3 replication from account to another account, which is replicating files to the the destination bucket in another account. I wanted to copy the exisiting objects in source account to my destination account and setup the S3 batch operation.

The IAM role was generated from aws console which i have added below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:InitiateReplication",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:kms:eu-:sourcekmskey",
                "arn:aws:kms:eu-:destinationkmskey"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::report-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i setup the S3 batch operation and run the batch job. The s3 batch job completes with the message: **Job completed with failures**

[image]

When i check the completion report, it shows a 500 error SrcGetObjectNotPermitted for some files. i have added ***s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication***  to my IAM role but still the i get the same error. I have checked the files KMS which is the same as all the rest of files

```
SrcGetObjectNotPermitted
```

Any idea how i can fix the SrcGetObjectNotPermitted for the files.

Comment: I see a typo, "source-bucke" must be "source-bucket"

Comment: those were just dummy names, i have updated the question